# Can't Insert Data into DataBase(SQL) using MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

This is my controller class

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignUp(SignupModel model)
        {
            User u = new User();
            u.LoginId = model.LoginId;
            u.Password = model.Password;
            u.FullName = model.FullName;
            new UsersHandler().AddUser(u);}
```

UserHandler class contains

```
public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            new DAC().Insert(user);
        }
```

DAC class contains the connections and UsersDAC contains the queries

***Insert Query***

```
internal void Insert(User user)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> temp = new List<SqlParameter> 
                                    {
                                        new SqlParameter("@FullName", user.FullName),
                                        new SqlParameter("@LoginId", user.LoginId),
                                        new SqlParameter("@Password", user.Password)       
                                    };
             SqlConnection con = DACHelper.GetConnection();
            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    user.Id = (int)DACHelper.ExecuteScalar(INSERT, temp, t);
                    DACHelper.Execute(INSERT, temp);
                    t.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    t.Rollback();
                }
            }

        }
```

> DACHelper.Execute(INSERT, temp);
>   It Executes but doesn't Insert any thing in table.

*Stored Procedure*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Users_Insert]
    @FullName           varchar(50),
    @LoginId            varchar(50),
    @Password           varchar(50)
AS
    Insert into [Users]
        ([FullName],[LoginId],[Password])
Values  (@FullName,@LoginId,@Password)

Select @@IDENTITY from [Users]
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? What does it not do correctly? I would recommend changing your last line of your INSERT procedure to just Select @@Identity, otherwise you get a value for every row in the table. Also, I would HIGHLY recommend you not store passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Well the Insert function does't works. Noting is inserted in the table.

Comment: Why not put something in your catch. The pattern you have here is what I call a try/squelch. It is NOT handling errors, it is suppressing them as if they didn't happen. Put something in there so the exception actually happens so you can find out what the problem is.

Comment: And you should be using SCOPE_IDENTITY not @@Identity. If you have a trigger on the Users table that inserts into a table with an identity you will get that value instead of the value from Users.

Comment: I have tried putting Exception in Catch block but it never occurs.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please stop saying 'doesn't work'. It indicates you have made no effort to analyse the issue. Can you confirm when you debug the INSERT method that it runs the `DACHelper.Execute(INSERT, temp);` line. **Then after that which line does it run?**

Comment: Okay I won't say that again. I have tried the same Insert method on a table which has no primary key  It work's fine. If I add a primary key suppose on ID field, INSERT method will not work. @nick.mcdermaid

Comment: will not work huh? How did your debugging go? What line did it run? Should I have even bothered making a comment?

Comment: Did you have the parenthesis on SCOPE_IDENTITY()?? It is a function with no parameters. You should step through your code in debugger. Either your insert procedure runs successfully OR you are getting an exception. I would recommend removing the try/catch entirely during development. Then putting in proper error handling when you know the code works under normal situations.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1. Test the stored procedure outside of your program using the same SQL credentials used by the program. If this works, the problem is your code.
2. Try calling the stored procedure by building the code without the use of your classes that hide some of what is being done.
3. Make sure that the `SqlCommand` object knows that it should be using a `CommandType` of `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.
4. Do not use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` or `@@IDENTITY`. The safest way to get the identity field is as follows (assume the field name is `ID`):

   `INSERT into [Users] ([FullName],[LoginID],[Password])
   OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
   VALUES (@FullName, @LoginID, @Password)`

This will always be the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

What about the commit mode? Is it in auto-commit mode. If not try to execute commit manually using the script. This should display message as transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have used sqlparamater.appwithvalue may be this cause this issue..

```
internal void Insert(User user)
{
    List<SqlParameter> temp = new List<SqlParameter> 
                                {
                                    new SqlParameter().AddWithvalue("@FullName", user.FullName),
                                    new SqlParameter().AddWithvalue("@LoginId", user.LoginId),
                                    new SqlParameter().AddWithvalue("@Password", user.Password)       
                                };
         SqlConnection con = DACHelper.GetConnection();
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                user.Id = (int)DACHelper.ExecuteScalar(INSERT, temp, t);
                DACHelper.Execute(INSERT, temp);
                t.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                t.Rollback();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal void Insert(User user)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> temp = new List<SqlParameter>
        {
            new SqlParameter("@LoginId", user.LoginId),
            new SqlParameter("@Password", user.Password),
            new SqlParameter("@FullName", user.FullName),

        };
        SqlConnection con = DACHelper.GetConnection();
        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlTransaction t = con.BeginTransaction();
            user.Id = (Int32)DACHelper.ExecuteScalar(INSERT, temp, t);
            t.Commit();
        }
  }
```

This will work by removing try/catch.